# Where can I find datatypes to which I can cast in polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Where can I find datatypes to which I can cast in polars?

This is the second time I am searching for this and I cannot find the right reference for them. There are types in the [User's Guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/datatypes.html), but it is not mentioned how to call those types. Also there is no mentioning of the data types in the [Python Documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the types you read in the user guide are available under the `polars` namespace. So:

```py
import polars as pl

# available data types
pl.Int8
pl.Int16
pl.Int32
pl.Int64
pl.UInt8
pl.UInt16
pl.UInt32
pl.UInt64
pl.Float32
pl.Float64
pl.Boolean
pl.Utf8
pl.List
pl.Date
pl.Datetime
pl.Duration
pl.Time
pl.Struct
pl.Object
```

Comment: Could we add it to the Python documentation?

Comment: See the user guide: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/datatypes.html